# History- calculating convolution by tabular method

Tags: ho.history-overview, na.numerical-analysis, signal-analysis, convolution

I often see a trick for calculating convolution of discrete data by a so-called Tabular method. There are a lot of Youtube videos and many Indian textbooks on Signal Processing [Books].[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=40CHRLqK5awC&pg=SA2-PA48&dq=convolution%20by%20tabulation%20method&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDqcTNreDnAhUEKqwKHXC4CdQQ6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=convolution%20by%20tabulation%20method&f=false)

Basically, if we have two series P = [1 3 5 3 1] and Q is [ 0 0 0 0.5 0.8 1 1 0 0 0]. One can make a table and multiply elements and sum up the diagonals as illustrated below. I color coded the diagonals. This process results in correct number of elements 10+5-1=14 elements.

Does anyone know who came up with this short cut? It seems like a nice approach for calculating convolution, correlation, cross correlation of discrete data.

Thanks.

[image: Tabular method]

Answer (score 2):

This reference claims to have invented the tabular method as a "novel method":

[A novel method for calculating the convolution sum of two finite length sequences](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1109/13.485235), J.W. Pierre (1996).

Three variations of the tabular method are discussed in [The use of spreadsheets to calculate the convolution sum of two finite sequences](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/93ed/e5335c04d07c264075462f0dd99e998c776d.pdf) (2004), citing a 1990 [text book.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135184738)

Comment: Thank you for the first reference on 1990. It is very nice. The 2004 reference shows the same approaches as I did in Excel with color coding but he cites reference 11, which is another South Asian author's textbook. I am sure, this approach must be older than 1990s. Also it seems this tabular of approach is quite popular in Indian engineering schools (as deduced from Youtube videos).

Comment: indeed, added the link to the text book.